# Checking linear program feasibility?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to check whether a certain linear program is feasible programmatically.  If I just type in an infeasible instance, such as

```
LinearProgramming[{1, 1}, {{-1, -1}}, {1}]
```

I get back an error, not an output indicating that it's infeasible.  What is the right way to get that behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `LinearProgramming` can do that directly. The documentation says: `LinearProgramming returns unevaluated if no solution can be found.`

However, checking the feasibility is a linear programming problem, too, so you could write a helper function like this:

```
feasibility[c_, m_, b_] := 
 Last[LinearProgramming[Append[0*c, 1], 
    ArrayFlatten[{{m, 1}, {0, 1}}], Append[b, 0]]] == 0
```

The idea is that I add a new variable/constraint pair that "loosens" the constraints, and minimize that variable. If it can be minimized to 0, then the constraints are feasible.

**EDIT**: I think it's possible that `LinearProgramming` returns a small nonzero value due to numerical inaccuracy. This version would prevent this:

```
Clear[feasability]
feasability[c_, m_, b_] := 
 With[{offset = 5 (*can be any positive number*)},
   Last[LinearProgramming[
      Append[0*c, 1], 
      ArrayFlatten[{{m, 1}}], 
      b + offset]] - offset] <= 0
```

Comment: If the input is rational, then checking for zero is fine, since LinearProgramming seems to use simplex.

Comment: @Louis: You're probably right. The second version should work with floating point and exact numbers, though.

Comment: Also, for the general form, extra slack variables are needed.  I'll post an extended version later.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following alternative, since it works with the general form of input to LinearProgramming

```
LPFeasible[c_, A_, b_] :=
  Not[Head[Quiet[LinearProgramming[c, A, b]]] === LinearProgramming]
```

I'm not really sure this is entirely guaranteed to keep working, though.

Comment: Wouldn't this be true whenever LinearProgramming throws an error, even if it's due to a syntax mistake?