# Low Tolerance making wrong behavior of LinearProgramming?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I was working on a code that needs to check feasibility of LP problems. I visited [Checking linear program feasibility?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124585/checking-linear-program-feasibility) and used the code. With this code, since there is 1 at the last position at every row on the constraint matrix, the message "LinearProgramming::lpsnf: No solution can be found that satisfies the constraints." should not happen. Though, I realized that this was happening in my code, and by stack trace I found that the code below has a problem.

```
LinearProgramming[{0, 
  1}, {{-0.46, 1}, {0.46 , 1}, {0.46, 1}, {-0.46, 1}, {0.0010, 
   1}, {0.46, 1}, {-0.46, 1}, {-0.46, 1}, {0.46, 1}, {0.0010, 1}, {0, 
   1}, {-0.23, 1}, {-0.26, 1}, {-0.26, 1}}, {0.17, -0.090, -0.13, 
  0.13, -0.045, -0.18, 0.087, 0.13, -0.13, 
  0.045, -1.57, -1.36, -0.53, -0.47}, 0, Tolerance -> 10^-30.]
```

As mentioned above, this code should not return a error message that says no solution, but it does in my computer. Fun fact about this is that if I change `Tolerance->10^-6`, error message disappers and works good. But since I need high precision, I can't give up with small tolerance, and even if I give up small tolerance, there might be same errors in different LP since my code would need to make lots of LP running. Is there some kind of time limit in the function `LinearProgramming` that makes `LinearProgramming` think there is no solution if the tolerance is too small and the function fails to find a solution before the time limit? If there is this kind of time limit, how can I get rid of it? If not, why is `LinearProgramming` reaching to a wrong result?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Use `Rationalize`? `LinearProgramming[{0, 1}, 
 Rationalize@{{-0.46, 1}, {0.46, 1}, {0.46, 1}, {-0.46, 1}, {0.0010, 
    1}, {0.46, 1}, {-0.46, 1}, {-0.46, 1}, {0.46, 1}, {0.0010, 1}, {0,
     1}, {-0.23, 1}, {-0.26, 1}, {-0.26, 1}}, 
 Rationalize@{0.17, -0.090, -0.13, 0.13, -0.045, -0.18, 0.087, 
   0.13, -0.13, 0.045, -1.57, -1.36, -0.53, -0.47}, 0]`

Comment: You say "I need high precision" but you are using machine precision input. This results in machine precision calculations, i.e., there is no attempt to track or control precision. That is why you must do either as @OkkesDulgerci suggests (`Rationalize` for exact input and exact calculations) or use `SetPrecision` to use arbitrary-precision calculations (track and control precision).

Comment: @BobHanlon @OkkesDulgerci Thanks for telling me that I was using only machine precision. I seems like using `Rationalize` does solve the problem. Still, I'm curious why just setting small tolerance would give wrong results in `LinearProgramming`. Can we see this as a bug of `LinearProgramming`?

Comment: `$MachinePrecision` is about 16 decimal digits. Using machine precision you cannot achieve tolerances of 10^-30.

Comment: @BobHanlon Oh, I understood. Thank you!